# VB.NET querystring has parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I check if a query string has a parameter in VB.NET? I'm having a hard time adapting C# code to VB.

I'm particularly interested in determining if a value-less/key-less parameter exists.

Pseudo-Code:

```
If Request.QueryString.Contains("test") Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Examples:

```
http://example.com/mypage.aspx?test
http://example.com/mypage.aspx?test=1
http://example.com/mypage.aspx?someparam=1&test&anotherparam=2
```

To clarify, I don't care whether or not `test` has a value. I just want to know if it is in the query string or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if Request.QueryString("test").Count > 0  then
    ...
end if
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Use:

```
If Request.QueryString.ToString.Contains("test") Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work for my scenario, but it is worth noting that there could be a match if the value of another parameter happens to contain the same `test` string in its value, i.e. `?someparam=test`.

Comment: @Quantastical shouldn't be much more complicated. In that case just additional check for actual values of key/value pairs should be checked in addition to above solution.

Comment: This is not a fully correct answer and should not be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

This should address both scenarios:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB"%>
<%
if Request.QueryString("test")<>"" then
  Response.Write ("EXISTS")
else 
  Response.Write ("not defined")
end if
%>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It does not answer correctly in case of `http://example.com/mypage.aspx?test, when the parameter is present, but does not have any value specified.